# Pyinstaller Hidden module not found error

Tags: python, pyinstaller

```
from ipregistry import IpregistryClient

with open('c:/temp2/details.txt', 'w') as outfile:

  client = IpregistryClient("tryout")
  ipInfo = client.lookup()
  print(ipInfo, file=outfile)
```

When converting this code with pyinstaller it gives

```
ERROR: Hidden import 'IpregistryClient' not found
```

but previously it used to work and I don't know why it doesn't works now, exe file is built and gives error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ipregistry'
```

I have installed ipregistry through pycharm and pip both

Comment: Is `ipregistry` module installed in the environment where you compile your module by `pyinstaller`?

Comment: Thanks for replying and as you can already guess I'm an absolute beginner so can you please elaborate it?

Comment: Have you been compiling your script in virtual environment? It looks like `pyinstaller` isn't being able to find `ipregistry` from packages list. It means either you haven't installed this module into your working virtual environment or you installed it to global environment while you compiling your script using a virtual one